# Error in Edwards's arclength proof?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

This question applies to Edwards's Advanced Calculus of Several Variables,
the proof of theorem V-1.1, page 288, etc.

> If $\vec{\gamma}:\left[t_0,t_{L}\right]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is
>   a $\mathscr{C}^1$ path, then $\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma}\right]$
>   exists, and $\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma}\right]=\int_{t_0}^{t_L}\left|\vec{\gamma}' [t]\right| \, dt$.

I did this for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. But replacing $3$ with $n$ will
generalize my demonstration. It was not my intent to ask if Edwards
was correct when I started writing this up, so I did it very much
my way. It was only when I happened upon his claim that $\left|\mathscr{P}\right|<\delta_1$ was a sufficient restriction to satisfy

$$\left|\mathfrak{t}_a-\mathfrak{t}_b\right|<\delta_1\implies\left|{\overset{*}{\gamma}}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_a\right]-{\overset{*}{\gamma}}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_b\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(t_L-t_0)},$$

that I came to believe Edwards was wrong about that. If someone has
a copy of Edwards's text, please have a look to see if I am reading
it correctly; and he was indeed mistaken. I contended he needs $\left|\mathscr{P}\right|<\frac{\delta_1}{\sqrt{n}}$, instead.

In either case, **could someone please verify my proof?** I acknowledge
it is a bit terse, and done using my own inventions.

---

Let $\vec{\gamma}:[t_0,t_L]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be a
smooth path in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To find the arclength:

Introduce the partition $\mathscr{P}=\left\{ t_0,\dots,<t_i,\dots,<t_k =t_L \right\} $ of the interval $\left[t_{0},t_{L}\right]$.

Write $\Delta t_i=t_i-t_{i-1}$.

Define the mesh of $\mathscr{P}$ as $\left|\mathscr{P}\right| \equiv \max[\Delta t_i]$.

Write $\Delta\vec{\gamma}_{i}=\vec{\gamma}\left[t_{i}\right]-\vec{\gamma}\left[t_{i-1}\right]$.

Define $ \overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}}_i\in\left[t_{i-1},t_i\right]^{3}$
as $\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}}_i=\left\{ \overset{*}{t_i^1},\overset{*}{t_i^2}, \overset{*}{t_i^3}\right\}$ such that $\Delta\vec{\gamma}_i=\left\{ {\gamma^1}' \left[\overset{*}{t_i^1}\right],{\gamma^2}'\left[\overset{*}{t_i^2}\right],{\gamma^3}' \left[\overset{*}{t_i^3}\right]\right\} \Delta t_i$.

Define $\overset{*}{\gamma}':\left[t_0,t_L\right]^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$
as $\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\mathfrak{t}\right]=\left\{ {\gamma^1}' [t^1], {\gamma^2}' [t^2], {\gamma^3}' [t^3] \right\} $.

Define $$\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_i}\right]\right|\Delta t_i=\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\Delta\vec{\gamma}_i\right|$$
which is not a proper Riemann sum.

Define $$\mathscr{R}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\vec{\gamma}'\left[t_i\right]\right|\Delta t_i \approx \sum_{i=1}^k \left|\Delta\vec{\gamma}_i\right|,$$
which is a proper Riemann sum.

Define $\mathfrak{t}_i\in\left[t_{i-1},t_i\right]^3$ as $\mathfrak{t}_i=\left\{ t_i,t_i,t_i\right\} $.
So ${\overset{*}{\gamma}}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_i\right] = \vec{\gamma}'[t_i]$.

Because $\vec{\gamma}$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$, the first derivatives
of the component functions ${\gamma^1}',{\gamma^2}',{\gamma^3}'$
are uniformly continuous on the closed and bounded interval $[t_0,t_L]^3$.
This means that given an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon>0$ there
is a $\delta_1>0$ such that for $\mathfrak{t}_a, \mathfrak{t}_b \in [t_0,t_L]^3$

$$\left|\mathfrak{t}_a-\mathfrak{t}_b\right|<\delta_1 \implies \left|\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_a \right]-\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\mathfrak{t}_b\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(t_L-t_0)}.$$

Applying the triangle inequality:

$$\left|\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\mathfrak{t}_{a}\right]\right|-\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_b\right]\right|\right| \le \left|\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_a\right]-\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_b\right] \right|.$$

So

$$\left|\mathfrak{t}_a-\mathfrak{t}_b\right|<\delta_1 \implies \left|\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_a\right]\right|-\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_b\right]\right|\right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(t_L-t_0)}.$$

Taking the difference of the polygonal approximation and the Riemann
sum gives

$$\left|\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]-\mathscr{R}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]\right|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_i} \right]\right| -\left|\vec{\gamma}' [t_i]\right|\right) \Delta t_i\right|$$

$$\le\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_i}\right]\right|-\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\mathfrak{t}_i\right]\right|\right|\Delta t_i.$$

If the mesh of the partition is restricted by $\left|\mathscr{P}\right|<\delta$,
since $\mathfrak{t}_i,\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_i}\in\left[t_{i-1},t_i\right]^3$ it follows that

$$\left|\mathfrak{t}_i-\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_i} \right| \le \delta \left|\left\{ 1,1,1\right\} \right|=\delta\sqrt{3}.$$

So, for $\left|\mathfrak{t}_{i}-\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_{i}}\right|<\delta_1$
to hold, the mesh shall be restricted to $\left|\mathscr{P}\right|<\frac{\delta_1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
This means that for each term

$$\left|\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}'\left[\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_i} \right]\right| -\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}' \left[\mathfrak{t}_i\right] \right| \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(t_L-t_0)}.$$

So

$$\left|\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]-\mathscr{R}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]\right|< \sum_{i=1}^k \frac \varepsilon {2(t_L-t_0)}\Delta t_i = \frac \varepsilon 2.$$

The function $\left|\vec{\gamma}' \left[t\right]\right|$ is
continuous on $\left[t_{0},t_{L}\right]$ and is, therefore, bounded.
Since it can be extended beyond $\left[t_{0},t_{L}\right]$ by specifying

$t\notin\left[t_{0},t_{L}\right]\implies\left|\vec{\gamma}'\left[t\right]\right|=0$,
it has bounded support. It is, therefore, integrable so that, given
$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that

$$\delta_2>\left|\mathscr{P}\right|\implies\left|\mathscr{R}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]-\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\left|\vec{\gamma}' [t] \right| \,dt\right| <\frac \varepsilon 2.$$

Taking $\delta=\min\left[\delta_1,\delta_2\right]$ implies

$$\left|\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]-\mathscr{R} \left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]\right| + \left|\mathscr{R} \left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]-\int_{t_0}^{t_L} \left|\vec{\gamma}' [t] \, \right| \, dt\right|<\varepsilon.$$

A sanity check $\left|a-b\right|=\left|\left(a-c\right)+\left(c-b\right)\right|\le\left|\left(a-c\right)\right|+\left|\left(c-b\right)\right|$
leads to

$$\delta>\left|\mathscr{P}\right|\implies\left|\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]-\int_{t_0}^{t_L}\left| \vec{\gamma}' [t]\right|\,dt\right|<\varepsilon.$$

That is

$$\lim_{\left|\mathscr{P}\right|\to0}\mathscr{s}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P} \right]=\lim_{\left|\mathscr{P}\right|\to0}\mathscr{R}\left[\vec{\gamma},\mathscr{P}\right]\equiv\int_{t_0}^{t_L}\left|\vec{\gamma}' [t]\right| \, dt$$

Also written

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_L}\left|\frac{d\vec{\gamma}}{dt}[t] \right| \,dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_L}\left|\vec{\gamma}'[t]\right| \, dt.$$

---

Verification of the triangle inequality application:

$$\left|a-b\right| = \left|a+c\right| \le \left|a\right| + \left|c\right| = \left|a\right| + \left|b\right|$$

$A=a+b$; $B=a-b$

$\left|A+B\right|\le\left|A\right|+\left|B\right|$

So

$$2\left|a\right|\le\left|a+b\right|+\left|a-b\right|\le\left|a-b\right|+\left|a\right|+\left|b\right|$$

$$\left|a\right|\le\left|a-b\right|+\left|b\right|$$

$$\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\le\left|a-b\right|$$

Let $C=-B$.

$$\left|A-B\right|=\left|A+C\right|\le\left|A\right|+\left|C\right|$$

$$\left|A-B\right|\le\left|A\right|+\left|B\right|$$

$$2\left|b\right|\le\left|a-b\right|+\left|a\right|+\left|b\right|$$

$$\left|b\right|-\left|a\right|\le\left|a-b\right|$$

$$\left|\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\right|\le\left|a-b\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

Edwards's proof is valid.  He never mentions the $\sqrt{n}$ explicitly, but his assertion that there is a $\delta_1$ satisfying the condition

$$\left|\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}^{\prime}\left[\overset{*}{\mathfrak{t}_{i}}\right]\right|-\left|\overset{*}{\gamma}^{\prime}\left[\mathfrak{t}_{i}\right]\right|\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(t_{L}-t_{0})}$$

is correct.  IIRC Alfred Gray does have the $\sqrt{n}$ in his proof, in the second edition of Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica.  But he crashed and burned with typos in that edition.

That is way different than what Edwards actually wrote, but meaning basically the same thing.